# How to check if string array only contains empty strings

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am currently looking for a solution how to check a string array with only empty strings. Is there an efficient way to achive this behavior?

```
['', '', '', ''] // This should be true
['', null, null, ''] // This should be true
['a', '', '', ''] // This should be false
```

Comment: Maybe I just expressed myself a bit unfortunate. I just really wanted to have a clean solution without, maybe something that exists in javascript already without reimplementing it or adding an additional loop for the sake of clean code.

Comment: if you mean a user defined loop (eg for loop or loops made by using some,every,forEach, etc) you could do a `join('')` (internal loop) and check for empty string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function:

```
let arr = ['', '', '', ''];
arr.some(Boolean);
```

it will check if some elements not false value ('', 0, null, undefined, false), if all of them are false; it will return true.

Answer (score 5):

You need a loop, preferably with a short circuit.

```js
const check = array => !array.some(Boolean);

console.log(check(['', '', '', '']));     //  true
console.log(check(['', null, null, ''])); //  true
console.log(check(['a', '', '', '']));    // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you incl. Patrick Evans.
I use the `join('')` method. This looks fairly clean to me.

```
let arr = ['', '', '', ''] // This should be true

console.log(Boolean(arr.join(''));
```

Comment: Join method will loop through all items; no matter what the element is, but some will break the loop and return value on first true element.